# Finding the best functions for different (x,y) points?

Tags: functions, approximation, matlab, mathematica

I have different (x,y) points and I want to find the best function that matches these points. However,I have 13 sets of these points. Here is some example of my data.

points 1:

```
{{0,0.5571018518518518}{1,0.34960185185185183}{2,0.0932962962962963}}
```

points 2:

```
{{0,0.5167687654320987}{1,0.31323246913580244}{2,0.14440802469135802}{3,0.02559074074074074}}
```

points 3:

```
{{0,0.491290658436214}{1,0.2860765843621399}{2,0.16438765432098765}{3,0.051488847736625515}{4,0.006756255144032922}}
```

To clarify what I need, I want to find a function of f(x) that is close to all these 3 points sets. Is there anyway in Mathematica or Matlab to do this? Or any formula ?

Thank you in advance.
if there is any problem in the question, please let me know so I can improve it.

Comment: Don't separate your points into several sets then.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am running different test cases with different values of x. It means for set 1 value of x are 0->2, set 2 from 0->3 and so on. These points are for different test runs.